# NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an xlsx file with a lot of data, and I have this script to insert data from the xlsx file into my own database:

```
file = 'lib/assets/sicepatfull.xlsx'
xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file)
sheet = xlsx.sheet(0)
attrs = sheet.row(1)
data = sheet.parse(header_search: attrs).map do |d|
  d.map {|k, v| [k.parameterize.underscore.to_sym, v] }.to_h.except :id
end
Courier.create!(data)
```

The command is cancelled after the `attrs`, and the result is: `NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory`.

How do I fix it?

Comment: how big is the xlsx file?

Answer (score 0):

`Roo` loads the whole file to memory, so if the file is big, it may just be too big for your RAM.

You can use alternative XLSX readers, e.g.

- [creek](https://github.com/pythonicrubyist/creek) - stream reader
- [rubyXL](https://github.com/weshatheleopard/rubyXL)

Comment: "Ruby only raises a NoMemoryError when memory allocation fails. It does not typically fire when the application itself exceeds the actual physical memory" https://airbrake.io/blog/ruby-exception-handling/nomemoryerror

Comment: Loadin whole file to RAM is OK for small files. For big ones it's a common practice to use stream processing (i.e. load a part of the file, process it, load another part etc).